# Plotly: Including additional data in hovertemplate

Tags: python, plotly

[image]                             hovertemplate=
'Continent: %{df['continent']}
'+
'Country: %{df['country']}
'+
'gdpPercap: %{x:,.4f} 
'+
'lifeExp: %{y}'+
''

I'm trying to use hovertemplate to customize hover information. However I can't get it to display what I want. I am getting x & y to work well. I can't figure out how to add other fields to the hovertemplate though. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
df = df[df['year'] == 1952]
customdata = np.stack((df['continent'], df['country']), axis=-1)
fig = go.Figure()
for i in df['continent'].unique():
    df_by_continent = df[df['continent'] == i]
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_by_continent['gdpPercap'], 
                         y=df_by_continent['lifeExp'],
                         mode='markers',
                         opacity=.7,
                         marker = {'size':15},
                         name=i,
                         hovertemplate=
                            'Continent: %{customdata[0]}<br>'+
                            'Country: %{customdata[1]}<br>'+
                            'gdpPercap: %{x:,.4f} <br>'+
                            'lifeExp: %{y}'+
                             '<extra></extra>',
                            ))
fig.update_layout(title="My Plot",
                 xaxis={'title':'GDP Per Cap',
                       'type':'log'},
                 yaxis={'title':'Life Expectancy'},
                )
fig.show()
```

Updated with more code. The first answer didn't work just returning the text value of comdata.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See below for an additional example of how to use `customdata` with multiple traces based on the code included in your question. Note that you actually need to add the `customdata` to the figure traces in order to use it in the `hovertemplate`, this was also shown in [Derek O](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69278586/11989081)'s answer.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv')
df = df[df['year'] == 1952]

fig = go.Figure()

for continent in df['continent'].unique():

    df_by_continent = df[df['continent'] == continent]

    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            x=df_by_continent['gdpPercap'],
            y=df_by_continent['lifeExp'],
            customdata=np.stack((df_by_continent['country'], df_by_continent['pop']), axis=-1),
            mode='markers',
            opacity=0.7,
            marker={'size': 15},
            name=continent,
            hovertemplate='<b>Country</b>: %{customdata[0]}<br>' +
                          '<b>Population</b>: %{customdata[1]:,.0f}<br>' +
                          '<b>GDP</b>: %{x:$,.4f}<br>' +
                          '<b>Life Expectancy</b>: %{y:,.2f} Years' +
                          '<extra></extra>',
        )
    )

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis={'title': 'GDP Per Cap', 'type': 'log'},
    yaxis={'title': 'Life Expectancy'},
)

fig.write_html('fig.html', auto_open=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't really understanding Derek O's answer but this helps it make more sense and worked.

Comment: Is there some way to limit the length of a string in the customdata field? For example values in the pandas array that are 100+ characters and you want to (using hovertemplate) to limit the string printed to only 20?

Comment: @Jono_R i don't think there's anyway to do that in plotly natively, but you can create a new column that truncates the existing column, and pass the new column to the customdata field

Comment: @DerekO I found a work around by using the hovertext field in the graph object and just creating a function which converts the information into the relevant list for plotting. There might be some speed impairment by doing this but for 2000+ points it is negligible compared to hovertemplate from my observations.

Answer (score 11):

For any other variables besides `{x}` and `{y}` in the `hovertemplate` string, you'll want to create a variable called `customdata` which is a numpy array of the DataFrame columns (`df['continent'], df['country']` in your case), and pass `customdata=customdata` to `fig.update_layout`. This is suggested by @empet in his Plotly forum answer [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-selecting-columns-in-dataframe-for-hovertemplate/33617/2).

You can try something like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder()

customdata = np.stack((df['continent'], df['country']), axis=-1)

fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp")

hovertemplate = ('Continent: %{customdata[0]}<br>' + 
    'Country: %{customdata[1]}<br>' + 
    'gdpPercap: %{x:,.4f} <br>' + 
    'lifeExp: %{y}' + 
    '<extra></extra>')

fig.update_traces(customdata=customdata, hovertemplate=hovertemplate)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: It didn't work for me. I'm getting the comdata text within my graph now.

Comment: [Derek O](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5327068/derek-o)'s answer is correct, your code is not working because you have not added the customdata to the figure traces.

Comment: Thank you! I understand it better now.

Comment: This code is not working. I am getting `KeyError: 'customdata'`

Comment: @ShaunHan did you copy this code exactly? i just tried it and it still works for me – i'm using the latest version of plotly

Comment: @DerekO OK I found out that it's due to string formatting. I have something like `continent = 'Asia'; hovertemplate = (f'{continent}: %{customdata[0]}<br>'`) which doesn't work. However, if I do `hovertemplate = (f'{continent}:' + '%{customdata[0]}<br>')`, it works somehow. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

A variation of the previous answers using just pandas/python:

```
customdata = list(df[['continent','country']].to_numpy())
```

Then compose your figure with a template referring to customdata as in the other answers.  For variation here's an example with Scatter3D and adding data from two columns of a dataframe:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

customdata_set = list(df[['transaction','type']].to_numpy())

fig = go.Figure(
    data=[go.Scatter3d(x=df.time,
                       y=df.source,
                       z=df.dest,
                       hovertemplate='<i>Source:</i>: %{y:i}<br>' +
                       '<i>Destination:</i>: %{z:i}<br>' +
                       '<i>Amount:</i>: $%{text}<br>' +
                       '<i>Txn #:</i>: %{customdata[0]}<br>' +
                       '<i>Txn Type:</i>: %{customdata[1]}<br>' +
                       '<i>Date:</i>: %{x|%Y-%m-%d}',
                       text=(df.amount).to_numpy(),
                       customdata = customdata_set,
                       mode='markers',
                       marker=dict(
                            color=moat_sql.tx_amount,
                            size=4,
                            opacity=.8,
                            showscale=True,
                            colorscale='Viridis',
                            colorbar=dict(
                                title=dict(text='Log Txn Amount',
                                           side='bottom',
                                           font={'color': 'red'}
                                           )
                            )
    )
    )]
)
```

Comment: If you want to access the 'color data' to show in the hovertemplate,  you can via `%{marker.color}`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `customdata + hovertemplate`, you can just pass formatted text to the `text` parameter directly. I found this simpler, and more powerful - for example if you don't want the exact same formatting for all elements.

So this actually works:

```python
text = your_df.map(
    lambda row: f'<i>Source:</i>: %{row.source:i}<br>' +
                    f'<i>Destination:</i>: %{row.z:i}<br>' +
                    f'<i>Amount:</i>: $%{row.amount}<br>' +
                    f'<i>Txn #:</i>: %{row.txn}<br>' +
                    f'<i>Txn Type:</i>: %{row.txn_type}<br>' +
                    f'<i>Date:</i>: %{row.date|%Y-%m-%d}',
    axis='columns'
)

go.Scatter3d(
   ...,
   text=text,
   ...
)
```

The `text` element doesn't support full HTML, but I've seen it support at least the `<br>` and `<b>` tags.
It does **not** seem to support `<h1>, <nbsp>, <hr>` tags.

I believe the same is true for `hovertemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example in Javascript using Plotly.js in case anyone is looking for it.:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.14.0.min.js"></script></head>
<body>
    <div id="myDiv" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>
    <script>
        // Define custom data
        const customData = [
            {
                x: [1, 2, 3],
                y: [4, 5, 6],
                z: ["Potato", "Banana", "Tomato"]
            }
        ];

        // Define custom hovertemplate
        const customHovertemplate = "X: %{x}<br>Y: %{y}<br>Z: %{customdata}";

        // Define trace using custom data and hovertemplate
        const trace = {
            x: customData[0].x,
            y: customData[0].y,
            customdata: customData[0].z,
            mode: "markers",
            marker: { color: "blue", size: 12 },
            type: "scatter",
            hovertemplate: customHovertemplate
        };

        Plotly.newPlot("myDiv", [trace]);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```