# Python Plotly display other information on Hover

Tags: python, python-3.x, plotly

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
# import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df = pd.read_csv("resultant_data.txt", index_col = 0, sep = ",")

display=df[["Velocity", "WinLoss"]]

pos = lambda col : col[col > 0].sum()
neg = lambda col : col[col < 0].sum()

Related_Display_Info = df.groupby("RacerCount").agg(Counts=("Velocity","count"), 
                                                   WinLoss=("WinLoss","sum"),
                                                  Positives=("WinLoss", pos),
                                                   Negatives=("WinLoss", neg),
                                                  )    

# Create figure with secondary y-axis
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=display.index, y=display["Velocity"], name="Velocity", mode="markers"),
    secondary_y=False
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x=Related_Display_Info.index, 
               y=Related_Display_Info["WinLoss"],
               name="Win/Loss", 
               mode="markers",
               marker=dict(
                           color=(
                                    (Related_Display_Info["WinLoss"] < 0)
                                 ).astype('int'),
                                colorscale=[[0, 'green'], [1, 'red']]
                           )
               ),
    secondary_y=True,
)

# Add figure title
fig.update_layout(
    title_text="Race Analysis"
)

# Set x-axis title
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="<b>Racer Counts</b>")

# Set y-axes titles
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>Velocity</b>", secondary_y=False)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>Win/Loss/b>", secondary_y=True)
fig.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")
fig.show()
```

The output is:
[image: images]

But I was willing to display the following information when I hover on the point:

```
RaceCount = From Display dataframe value Number of the race corresponding to the dot I hover on.  
Velocity  = From Display Dataframe value Velocity at that point  
Counts    = From Related_Display_Info Column  
WinLoss   = From Related_Display_Info Column  
Positives = From Related_Display_Info Column  
Negatives = From Related_Display_Info Column
```

Please can anyone tell me what to do to get this information on my chart?

I have checked this but was not helpful since I got many errors: [Python/Plotly: How to customize hover-template on with what information to show?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59057881/python-plotly-how-to-customize-hover-template-on-with-what-information-to-show)

**Data:**

```
RacerCount,Velocity,WinLoss
111,0.36,1
141,0.31,1
156,0.3,1
141,0.23,1
147,0.23,1
156,0.22,1
165,0.2,1
174,0.18,1
177,0.18,1
183,0.18,1
114,0.32,1
117,0.3,1
120,0.29,1
123,0.29,1
126,0.28,1
129,0.27,1
120,0.32,1
144,0.3,1
147,0.3,1
159,0.27,1
165,0.26,1
168,0.25,1
156,0.29,1
165,0.26,1
168,0.26,1
165,0.28,1
213,0.17,1
243,0.15,1
249,0.14,1
228,0.54,1
177,0.67,1
180,0.66,1
183,0.65,1
192,0.66,1
195,0.62,1
198,0.6,1
180,0.66,1
222,0.56,1
114,0.41,1
81,0.82,1
102,0.56,1
111,0.55,1
90,1.02,1
93,1.0,1
90,1.18,1
90,1.18,1
93,1.1,1
96,1.07,1
99,1.04,1
102,0.99,1
105,0.94,1
108,0.92,1
111,0.9,1
162,0.66,1
159,0.63,1
162,0.65,-1
162,0.66,-1
168,0.64,-1
159,0.68,-1
162,0.67,-1
174,0.62,-1
168,0.65,-1
171,0.64,-1
198,0.55,-1
300,0.47,-1
201,0.56,-1
174,0.63,-1
180,0.61,-1
171,0.64,-1
174,0.62,-1
303,0.47,-1
312,0.48,-1
258,0.51,-1
261,0.51,-1
264,0.5,-1
279,0.47,-1
288,0.48,-1
294,0.47,-1
258,0.52,-1
261,0.51,-1
267,0.5,-1
222,0.53,-1
171,0.64,-1
177,0.63,-1
177,0.63,-1
```

Comment: Does anyone needs any more information regarding not understanding or anything please let me know. I am willing to have the solution for this question.

Comment: This is pretty similar to a question I've answered before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69278251/plotly-including-additional-data-in-hovertemplate), except that you're pulling data from two different sources: `display` and `Related_Display_Info`. as long as these two dataframes are the same length, you should be able to pass the required columns to the hovertemplate the same way as in the answer above

Comment: @DerekO Thank you for your reply. The two data frame has different lengths unfortunately. But there X axis has same values so I was able to plot things effectively without issue. But display the information is required. I will check your reference too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, this code ungroups the data frame before plotting to create the `hovertemplate` you're looking for.
As stated in the comments, the data has to have the same number of rows to be shown in the `hovertemplate`. At the end of my answer, I added the code all in one chunk.

> Since you have `hovermode` as `x unified`, you probably only want one of these traces to have hover content.

I slightly modified the creation of `Related_Display_Info`. Instead of `WinLoss`, which is already in the parent data frame, I modified it to `WinLoss_sum`, so there wouldn't be a naming conflict when I ungrouped.

```
Related_Display_Info = df.groupby("RacerCount").agg(
    Counts=("Velocity","count"), WinLoss_sum=("WinLoss","sum"),
    Positives=("WinLoss", pos), Negatives=("WinLoss", neg))
```

Now it's time to ungroup the data you grouped. I created `dui` (stands for display info ungrouped).

```
dui = pd.merge(df, Related_Display_Info, how = "outer", on="RacerCount", 
               suffixes=(False, False))
```

I created the `hovertemplate` for both traces. I passed the entire ungrouped data frame to `customdata`. It looks like the only column that isn't in the template is the original `WinLoss`.

```
# create hover template for all traces
ht="<br>".join(["<br>RacerCount: %{customdata[0]}",
                "Velocity: %{customdata[1]:.2f}",
                "Counts: %{customdata[3]}",
                "Winloss: %{customdata[4]}",
                "Positives: %{customdata[5]}",
                "Negatives: %{customdata[6]}<br>"])
```

The creation of `fig` is unchanged. However, the traces are both based on `dui`. Additionally, the index isn't `RacerCount`, so I used the literal field instead.

```
# Create figure with secondary y-axis
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dui["RacerCount"], y=dui["Velocity"], 
                         name="Velocity", mode="markers",
                         customdata=dui, hovertemplate=ht), 
              secondary_y=False)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x = dui["RacerCount"], y=dui["WinLoss_sum"], customdata=dui,
               name="Win/Loss", mode="markers", 
               marker=dict(color=((dui["WinLoss_sum"] < 0)).astype('int'),
                           colorscale=[[0, 'green'], [1, 'red']]), 
                           hovertemplate=ht),
    secondary_y=True)
```

[image]

[image]

All the code altogether (for easier copy + paste)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

df = pd.read_clipboard(sep = ',')

display=df[["Velocity", "WinLoss"]]

pos = lambda col : col[col > 0].sum()
neg = lambda col : col[col < 0].sum()

Related_Display_Info = df.groupby("RacerCount").agg(
    Counts=("Velocity","count"), WinLoss_sum=("WinLoss","sum"),
    Positives=("WinLoss", pos), Negatives=("WinLoss", neg))

# ungroup the data for the hovertemplate
dui = pd.merge(df, Related_Display_Info, how = "outer", on="RacerCount", 
               suffixes=(False, False))

# create hover template for all traces
ht="<br>".join(["<br>RacerCount: %{customdata[0]}",
                "Velocity: %{customdata[1]:.2f}",
                "Counts: %{customdata[3]}",
                "Winloss: %{customdata[4]}",
                "Positives: %{customdata[5]}",
                "Negatives: %{customdata[6]}<br>"])

# Create figure with secondary y-axis
fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dui["RacerCount"], y=dui["Velocity"], 
                         name="Velocity", mode="markers",
                         customdata=dui, hovertemplate=ht), 
              secondary_y=False)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(x = dui["RacerCount"], y=dui["WinLoss_sum"], customdata=dui,
               name="Win/Loss", mode="markers", 
               marker=dict(color=((dui["WinLoss_sum"] < 0)).astype('int'),
                           colorscale=[[0, 'green'], [1, 'red']]), 
                           hovertemplate=ht),
    secondary_y=True)

# Add figure title
fig.update_layout(
    title_text="Race Analysis"
)

# Set x-axis title
fig.update_xaxes(title_text="<b>Racer Counts</b>")

# Set y-axes titles
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>Velocity</b>", secondary_y=False)
fig.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>Win/Loss/b>", secondary_y=True)
fig.update_layout(hovermode="x unified")
fig.show()
```

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you fr this answer.