# Pandas plot with Plotly backend and Custom Hover template

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I am trying to include additional data in the hover template, similar to this [Plotly: Including additional data in hovertemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69278251/plotly-including-additional-data-in-hovertemplate), but using Plotly plotting backend on Pandas.

I have two 2D Pandas data frames, the first is the population by country and by year, and the second is the percent population growth by country and by year, generated with the following codes.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.plotting.backend = 'plotly'

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv')
df_pop = df.pivot_table(index='year', columns='country', values='pop').copy()
df_pct_growth = df_pop.pct_change().fillna(0) * 100
```

**df_pop**:
[image]

**df_pct_growth**:
[image]

---

I visualized the population for each country as follows. As you can see, the hover text only has the **country**, **year**, and **population**. I want to add the **% growth** from the **df_pct_growth** into the hover text. Does anyone know how to do that?

```
df_pop.plot(labels=dict(value='Population'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not seen any examples of using custom data with the 'Plotly' backend. Looking at the graph structure, I thought it might be possible to add custom data and update the hover template. The code I added would set the country name to meta. (which could provide the same functionality as the custom data) and set the column data for the growth rate by country as custom data. The hover template was accomplished by adding a growth rate field.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
pd.options.plotting.backend = 'plotly'

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv')
df_pop = df.pivot_table(index='year', columns='country', values='pop').copy()
df_pct_growth = df_pop.pct_change().fillna(0) * 100

fig = df_pop.plot(labels=dict(value='Population'))

for i,country in enumerate(df.country.unique()):
    fig.data[i]['meta'] = country
    fig.data[i]['customdata'] = df_pct_growth.loc[:,country].to_frame().values
    fig.data[i]['hovertemplate'] = 'country: %{meta}<br>year: %{x}<br>population: %{y:,}<br>growth: %{customdata[0]:.2f}<extra></extra>'

fig.show()
```

[image]

**Plotly code without backend**

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

for country in df.country.unique():
    dff = df.query('country == @country')
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=dff['year'],
                             y=dff['pop'],
                             mode='lines',
                             name=country,
                             meta=country,
                             customdata=df_pct_growth.loc[:,country].to_frame().values,
                             hovertemplate=
                             'country: %{meta}<br>' + 
                             'year: %{x}<br>' +
                             'population: %{y:,}<br>' +
                             'growth: %{customdata[0]:.2f}' + 
                             '<extra></extra>'
                         ))
fig.show()
```